# Como listar pais e cidade em angularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

Quero fazer o seguinte:

Brasil  Rio Grade do Sul
Brasil  Rio de Janeiro
... e assim sucessivamente.

Tem como fazer isso em uma tabela?

```
<table width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="200" align="center">País</td>
        <td width="300" align="center">Estado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{pais}}</td>
        <td>{{estado}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

País e estado estão cada um em uma tabela.

Comment: Por favor adicione mais detalhes a sua pergunta, incluindo o código que já tem, como você está obtendo os dados e o resultado esperado (caso seja este o problema).

Comment: Sö tenho o html, mas não o controller para exibir os dados.

Comment: Mas já foi o suficiente para entender como você queria o retorno, fiz um exemplo pra você na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo completo usando o seu retorno esperado.

Voce pode executar o código para testar.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('EstadosController', function() {
    var estados = this;
    estados.lista = [{
      pais: 'Brasil',
      estado: 'Rio Grande do Sul'
    }, {
      pais: 'Brasil',
      estado: 'Santa Catarina'
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="EstadosController as estados">
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <table width="500" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td width="200" align="center">País</td>
          <td width="300" align="center">Estado</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="estado in estados.lista">
          <td>{{estado.pais}}</td>
          <td>{{estado.estado}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Caso resolva seu problema, por favor aceite a resposta e vote a favor.

Comment: Vou tentar, valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim, e é bem simples. Basta fazer isso:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dados in meuScope">
    <td>{{dados.pais}}</td>
    <td>{{dados.estado}}</td>
</tr>
```

Onde `meuScope` é o valor de `$scope` definido no `controller`.

Exemplo:

```
$scope.meuScope = [
    {pais: 'Brasil', estado: 'Rio de Janeiro'},
    {pais: 'Brasil', estado: 'São Paulo'},
    //etc...
];
```